# Настройка ЧПУ с помощью htaccess и 301 редирект

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Имеется сайт на старом самописном движке на php.
На сайте имеются ссылки вида:

> site.ru/index.php?page=services
>
> site.ru/index.php?page=services&cat=category              (1)
>
> site.ru/index.php?page=services&cat=category&id=stranitsa

Настроил ЧПУ ссылки вида

> site.ru/services
>
> site.ru/services/category                     (2)
>
> site.ru/services/category/stranitsa

с помощью файла .htaccess :

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&cat=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\/([a-z0-9-]+)\/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&cat=$2&id=$3 [L]
  </IfModule>
```

Получается что страница доступна по двум ссылкам (1) и (2). А нужно чтобы с (1) шел 301й редирект на (2). 
Посдскажите, пжлста, как это сделать?

Пробовал ниже\выше указанных инструкций написать что-то вроде:

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]*)$
  RewriteRule ^index.php /%1? [R=301]
```

Но заходя на **site.ru/services** получается бесконечная цикличная переадресация..